# utf8 not supporting for other languages why?

Tags: php, html

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

it is not working like i have my site which can be translated  in 20 languages but in some languages like turkish , japanese it shows � symbol instead of space or " and many others

Comment: Are you sure your source files are in UTF-8?

Comment: Where is your content coming from? If everything is in UTF-8 and you set the charset correctly then there should be no problem!

Comment: http://www.my-gogaku-ryugaku.jp/gogaku/KURUS-ENGLISH here is the link and the content in page is comming from database admin add the content but this problem occurs

Comment: Where does the problem occur? I've had a look at the page with Opera and switched to Turkish, but I couldn't see any obvious error. Is the error visible on this page and if so, can you name language + browser?

Comment: languages are turkish and japnese , i have removed only the space and &nbsp; from the admin side so it disappears but the html entities like &nbsp is not working in my site , and it occurs on all browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for php, you need to add a utf-8 header

```
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Answer (score 2):

Since I don't know your site I can just guess in the dark.

Setting

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

will not be the only thing you have to do. If your document is saved as ASCII your problems won't be solved. Additionally you have to set the document encoding correctly (the meta tag just tells the browser which encoding to use, not which one IS actually used). So open the document with a (good) text editor like SublimeText / Notepad++ or what you prefer and set the encoding to UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

Letting know browser that text is in unicode and actually providing data in unicode is not the same. Check your files for unicode, database data for unicode and transformation that is done with it while serving. Provide more information to pinpoint your problem

Comment: if i put &nbsp; from admin panel in the content of any school � this symbol appears intstead of space

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
> ```

Just adding a Content-Type header in HTML doesn't make anything utf-8. It merely tells the browser to expect utf-8. If your source files are not in utf-8, or the database columns in which data is stored isn't utf-8, or if the connection to the database itself isn't utf-8, or if you're sending a HTTP header telling it isn't utf-8, it will not work. There's just one way of dealing with utf-8: make sure everything *is* in utf-8.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the admin tool you are using. The tool injects data into a UTF-8 encoded data in some other encoding. As the tool has not been described, the specific causes cannot be isolated. The pages mentioned do not exhibit the problem, and they specify the UTF-8 encoding in HTTP headers, so the `meta` tag is ignored in the online context (though useful for offline use).